# WPF Grid different Column Size & Position

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to achieve this kind of grid:

[image]

so I need to have a Grid where two columns can be different if they are in different rows. (also the same should be possible for rows).

My grid so far looks something like this

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Content="Left" Grid.Column="0" />
        <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              Grid.Column="1" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
              Width="5" Background="#FFBCBCBC"/>
    <Label Content="Right" Grid.Column="2" />

    <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  ResizeDirection="Rows"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
              Height="5" Background="#FFBCBCBC"/>

    <Label Content="Left" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
              Width="5" Background="#FFBCBCBC"/>
    <Label Content="Right" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" />
</Grid>
```

How can I make this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use multiple `Grids` inside like this:

```
   <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- First Row-->
        <Grid>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <Label Content="Left" Grid.Column="0" />

            <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                          Grid.Column="1" 
                          ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
                          Width="5" 
                          Background="#FFBCBCBC"
                          />

            <Label Content="Right" 
                   Grid.Column="2" 
                   />
        </Grid>



        <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  ResizeDirection="Rows"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
              Height="5" Background="#FFBCBCBC"/>

        <!-- Second Row -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <Label Content="Left" 
                   Grid.Column="0" 
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   />

            <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                          Grid.Column="1" 
                          Grid.Row="2" 
                          ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
                          Width="5" 
                          Background="#FFBCBCBC"
                          />

            <Label Content="Right" 
                   Grid.Column="2" 
                   Grid.Row="2" 
                   />

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
```

In the end you dont want to effect other rows by the `GridSplitter` - so just use a `Grid` per row. This is normaly not so good and you would prefer `Grid.ColumnSpan` and `Grid.RowSpan`, but in your problem this is the most trivial solution.

[image: Result]

Comment: This looks like the one I am trying to achieve.
The system I am working on is a more dynamic system, I just posted an example.

I just did not know if this is the right way to do this. But seems so.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Vertically use 3 rows, and 1st and 3rd row has 3 columns each. The 3 rows' columns don't align to each other.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          ResizeDirection="Rows"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
          Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="1" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
          Height="5" Background="#FFBCBCBC"/>

    <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          ResizeDirection="Rows"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
          Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="3" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
          Height="5" Background="#FFBCBCBC"/>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
          Grid.Column="1"  ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
          Width="5" Background="#FFBCBCBC"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="4">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
          Grid.Column="1"  ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
          Width="5" Background="#FFBCBCBC"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is kinda the same as the one before and is what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution depends on do you want solution for single problem shown in image or do you want generic solution.
For this particular setup, you can define three columns, then for first row, use first column regularly and for second add `Grid.ColumnSpan=2` to a child controls. This will merge second and third column.
For second row, use `Grid.ColumnSpan=3` and all columns will be merged.
For second row, use `Grid.ColumnSpan=2` for things in first column.

You can use similar approach in different configurations. However, if you want completely generic solution, you can't do it with regular Grid and you would have to implement your own grid control with column definitions for each row and calculating layout of child controls.